# How to save multiple parseObject with progresscallback

Tags: android, callback, parse-platform, android-progressbar

I am currently writing a program in which I need to upload multiple parseObjects like this:

```
List<ParseObject> listObjects;
ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(listObjects, new SaveCallback() { 

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
    }
}
```

But when the list increases, I need a way of notifying user the save progress is underway...
[ParseFile](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html) has a built in

```
ParseFile.saveInBackground(SaveCallback saveCallback, ProgressCallback progressCallback)
```

My question is, how do I implement progresscallback using parseobject. If it's not possible, do I have to convert my parseobject to a parsefile?